# Ruby on rails method partials?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was wondering if it is possible to create a method partial in ruby on rails, for example I have this code;-

```
@cart = Cart.where(:user_id => current_user.id).first if user_signed_in?
@slots = @cart.slots.first
@slot_list = [@slots.slot_one, @slots.slot_two, @slots.slot_three, @slots.slot_four, @slots.slot_five,
              @slots.slot_six, @slots.slot_seven, @slots.slot_eight, @slots.slot_nine, @slots.slot_ten]
@user_products = []
@product = []
@slot_list.each do |item|
  if item.nil?
    p 'Item empty'
  else
    @product << item
  end
end
@product.each do |item|
  items = Product.where(:product_id => item).first
  @user_products << items
end
```

Written in multiple methods to get the @user_products, I was wondering if there was a way so I don't have to write this all the time and possibly run a method or use a partial?

Would it be worth creating a helper that does this and returns the @user_products variable?

Comment: yes, in ruby you can extract things into methods. "Extract method" is probably the most common refactoring technique (right after "Rename", of course).

Comment: Hello I have just posted an answer and created two helper methods, would these be okay to use?

Comment: Hey, Adam - I can set up a chat, if you like, so we can discuss this without a long comment thread. LMK.

Answer (score 0):

I took my own advice and created two helpers, one to return the @user_products and another to return the @total.

I added the names of the methods to our helper_method

```
helper_method :user_is_admin?, :authenticate_admin!, :product_available?, :get_user_products!, :get_user_total!
```

then added these two methods at the bottom of the file;-

**get_user_products!**

```
def get_user_products!
      @cart = Cart.where(:user_id => current_user.id).first if user_signed_in?
    @slots = @cart.slots.first
    @slot_list = [@slots.slot_one, @slots.slot_two, @slots.slot_three, @slots.slot_four, @slots.slot_five,
                  @slots.slot_six, @slots.slot_seven, @slots.slot_eight, @slots.slot_nine, @slots.slot_ten]
    @user_products = []
    @product = []
    @slot_list.each do |item|
    if item.nil?
        p 'Item empty'
      else        
        @product << item
    end
    end
      @product.each do |item|
      items = Product.where(:product_id => item).first
      @user_products << items
    end
    return @user_products
end
```

**get_user_total!**

```
def get_user_total!
@total = 0
    @cart = Cart.where(:user_id => current_user.id).first if user_signed_in?
    @slots = @cart.slots.first
    @slot_list = [@slots.slot_one, @slots.slot_two, @slots.slot_three, @slots.slot_four, @slots.slot_five,
                  @slots.slot_six, @slots.slot_seven, @slots.slot_eight, @slots.slot_nine, @slots.slot_ten]

    @user_products = []
    @product = []
    @slot_list.each do |item|
    if item.nil?
        p 'Item empty'
      else        
        @product << item
    end
    end
      @product.each do |item|
      items = Product.where(:product_id => item).first
      @user_products << items
    end
    @user_products.each do |p|
      @total += p.product_price
    end
    return @total
end
```

To use these methods inside whatever controller you then do the following;-

```
@user_products = get_user_products!
@total = get_user_total!
```

Comment: For a long time, I put stuff like this in helpers. I now think it's a Bad Idea. Here's a piece you might find interesting - http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/ My preference is to go the PORO route. As a bonus, POROs are way easier to test than conrollers (in RSpec).

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is in a controller?

What you want is to use plain old Ruby objects (POROs). So, you might have something like this:

```
  class UserProducts
    class << self

      def get(options={})
        @cart = Cart.where(:user_id => current_user.id).first if user_signed_in?
        @slots = @cart.slots.first
        @slot_list = [
          @slots.slot_one, 
          @slots.slot_two, 
          @slots.slot_three, 
          @slots.slot_four, 
          @slots.slot_five,
          @slots.slot_six, 
          @slots.slot_seven, 
          @slots.slot_eight, 
          @slots.slot_nine, 
          @slots.slot_ten
        ]

      @user_products = []
      @product = []
      @slot_list.each do |item|
        if item.nil?
          p 'Item empty'
        else                
          @product << item
        end
      end
      @product.each do |item|
        items = Product.where(:product_id => item).first
        @user_products << items
      end
    end
  end
```

Then, in your controller, you'd do something like:

```
class FooController < ApplicationController
  def index
    UserProducts.get(user_id: current_user.id)
  end
end
```

So, `UserProducts` is essentially a service object. I think some people call them use cases. I tend to call them 'managers'. I put them in their own directory as `app/managers/user_products.rb`.

Comment: Hey I know it's been a while since this, but I just tried this today - I realised what you mean by the helpers now... I've learned my lesson it's getting too full of methods. I tried this however I can't seem to access the UserManger class when it is in it's own folder like app/managers it has to be in the same folder as the controller that uses it how do I make this work?

Comment: Hm. Which rails are you using? It should autoload unless you have minor errors in folder names and/or namespaces. What's your manager name? What are your directory structures? Do you get an constant error?

Comment: I am using Rails4.2.5 and I tried putting the folder in app/managers/userManger.rb then tried app/controllers/managers/user_manager.rb.

Comment: Also is there a way to get the current user inside of the managers?